# Update a value in a MySQL loop if matches with a condition

Tags: php, mysql

Ok, I'm probably pushing myself too much over my MySQL's skills, but here's my question: I have a table where I store the categories of the products giving them a sort order specified in the `sort` column

```
-----------------------
|   category   | sort |
|---------------------|
|  category3   |  1   |
|  category1   |  2   |
|  category2   |  3   |
-----------------------
```

When I display the categories, I display them `ORDER BY sort ASC`. Now I want to give the admin the possibility to change the sort order and what I would do is something like extract the categories associated to the sort number and working them in PHP, adding `+1` to the numbers that follow the position where the admin wants to place the category and sending multiple queries to the db updating all the `sort` values.

(i.e if the admin wants the category2 at position n.1, I would extract * the sort values adding +1 from 1-2, 3 excluded)

Since I think this is the most inefficient method and I was wondering if I can do all just with a MySQL query. For this reason I thought at something like this

```
$sql = 'CREATE PROCEDURE rowperrow()
        BEGIN 
            SET @position = '.$newCatPosition.'
            DECLARE rowNum INT DEFAULT 0
            DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0
            SELECT COUNT(*) FROM productsareas INTO rowNum
            SET i=0
            WHILE i<rowNum DO
                SELECT @sortNum = sort FROM productsareas
                IF @sortNum>@position-1 THEN 
                    UPDATE productsareas SET sort=@sortNum +1
                END IF
                SET i=i+1
            END WHILE
        END';
```

This query should check row-per-row if the sort number is `> $newCatPosition-1` (that is the correspondent number where the admin wants to place the category -1, 'cause also the same number has to be incremented of +1 to left the space to the new category): if true, it replaces the sort number incrementing it of `+1`.

It's useless saying that I tried this query and it doesn't work, but the result I want to obtain is similar to what I wrote

Comment: can you do it with just "update table set sort=sort+1 where sort<=$newPos"?

Comment: @Dimi That's great, I thought I needed to extract the sort value into a loop to achieve this result but instead it was so clear. Thanks mate